# Update rows with where condition returning multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

Consider the following two tables

Table A

```
ID | Name | Price | Size
1    aaa    10      L
2    bbb    12      L
3    ccc    15      L
4    ddd    20      XL
```

Table B

```
ID | Type 
1     X
2     X
3     Y
4     Z
```

Now I want to update the price attribute of table A by 1% where the size is L and the Type is X. I wrote this update statement

```
UPDATE A SET price =  price * 1.01
WHERE size = 'L' AND id = (SELECT id FROM B WHERE type = 'X');
```

But this gives me

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row error.

I know that the problem is in "id = (SELECT id FROM B WHERE type = 'X');" because it is giving multiple values.

Give me some idea about how can I resolve this issue.

Comment: `id = (` --> `id in (`

Comment: @Pரதீப்  I don't understand, explain with a bit of details please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This select returns 2 rows

```
SELECT id FROM B WHERE type = 'X'
```

Result

```
ID | Type
1    X
2    X
```

Thus, use `IN` if you compare value to select that returns multiple rows

```
UPDATE A 
  SET price =  price * 1.01
 WHERE size = 'L' 
   AND id IN (SELECT id FROM B WHERE type = 'X');
```

Comment: It was a simple thing I knew it thanks for your breif explanation. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE a SET a.price =  a.price * 1.01 from A a
Inner join B b on a.id =  b.id where b.type = 'X' and a. size = 'L' ;